# How to auto-left justify text in personal kindle documents

Tags: send-to-kindle

I use the 'Send to Kindle' for Google Chrome extension to send longform articles to my Kindle. It works great, except that it seems to force justify text flush both left and right. I have a vision problem and read at the largest text size, which creates unsightly gaps in the text.

This post: [How can I left justify text on my Kindle?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/682/how-can-i-left-justify-text-on-my-kindle) covers how to handle it for existing books, but I am wondering if there is a solution for documents scraped from the web, ideally as part of an integrated browser extension.

If not browser extension based, what is the suggested workflow for `web article` → `ebook creation software` → `kindle personal docs`?

Comment: What about http://grabmybooks.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

HTML has to be clean for conversions. Often webpages may use custom/extra styles which confuse Kindle or these plugins.

One idea would be to paste the contents onto a MS Word file and then send the MS Word file to Kindle.

Paste the text of article to MS Word from a web browser. (Make sure to choose to paste TEXT ONLY). Apply only two styles: HEADING1 to the headline and NORMAL to the body. Don't manually style anything.

If you want, you could right-click the NORMAL style button and make sure justified is checked. But I'm not sure it will work (or it is even necessary).

At that point, you can send to kindle. Because Kindle is receiving a clean/unformatted document, it should convert it fairly well.

I actually think that sending a MS Word doc to Kindle is a lot easier than some of these browser-based plugins. Of course, you may end up losing lists, centering, colors, etc.

Comment: thanks, that's useful context. for anyone reading this, I ended up using https://dotepub.com/ and syncing to the reader Marvin for iOS, which ended up being much more flexible (custom themes, fonts, etc). Thanks!

Comment: how does dotepub compare to the chrome plugin "send to kindle"?

Comment: @toomey8 did you manage to left align your text?